# Successive ImageViews in a loop

Tags: android, imageview, drawable

I am working on an app where I have to set up a number of drawables. The number depends on the user input.
I therefore need to use a loop there I set up as many successive images as the user have chosen in one or several rows.

I can not find out how. I know how to put the images in an array and use
    (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img)
to set them up. But I want to create this successive ImageViews in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

try to make a combinatino of LinearLayout and LayoutInflater (to inflate custom views)

```
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);

    for (int i = 0; i < userChoice; i++)
    {
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(yourContext);
        View customView = li.inflate(R.layout.image_holder, this);
        // (In case you need to use the image) ImageView yourImage = (ImageView)customView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        layout.addView(customView);
    }
```

where:

userChoice is the number the user has choose

layout is linear layout inside your main.xml (or the root element itself)

image_holder is an xml with ImageView inside it

Comment: Thank you very mutch! This helped. In conjunction with rows in table layout this solved the problem.